# After updating to macOS 10.14 (Majove) XCUITest failed to execute test case saying "Failed to set pid 2102 as responsible for 20210"

Tags: xcuitest, xcode9.4, macos-mojave

I have updated my MacBook to Mojave (10.14), after that UI test is failing with the following error.
 _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=9 "Failed to set pid 2102 as responsible for 20210" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to set pid 2102 as responsible for 20210}

Any suggestion on this?

Already tried of clean build, clearing derived data and Restarting the machine.

Comment: which beta version you use?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: Edit Scheme -> Test Action and uncheck "Debug executable" checkbox. Also this fixes the same problem with framework tests.

[image]